# Check file extension in sftp batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have one bat file which checks for .csv file in sftp location.

If csv file is present on sftp server, then it successfully downloads the file in local and exit with 0.

If .csv file is not present, then bat file completes processing with exit status 1.

I am using below bat file for sftp:

```
echo open sftp://<username>:<password><server_name> -hostkey="<server host key>" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo get /shared/sftp/test.csv >> ftpcmd.dat
echo exit >> ftpcmd.dat
D:\Winscp\winscp.com /script=ftpcmd.dat
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Problem -
I need to check for file extension also in same script, as part of the requirement. If in sftp server location, a file with other extensions is present, then sftp script will fail or exit with some status.

Current behavior -
If .txt file is present in sftp location, then batch file is exiting with status 1. I need to exit this condition with some other exit status.

Please suggest how can i implement this file extension checking condition in same bat file which sftp the file.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward/simplistic approach would be to additionally check for `.txt` when there is no `.csv` and in case of success set the exit code to 2:

```
for %%a in (csv txt) do (
    winscp.com /command ^
        "open sftp://<username>:<password><server_name> -hostkey=""<server host key>""" ^
        "get /shared/sftp/test.%%a" ^
        "exit"
    if "%errorlevel%" equ 0 if %%a==csv (exit /b 0) else (exit /b 2)
)
```

Exit codes:

- 0: CSV was downloaded
- 1: CSV and TXT both are absent
- 2: TXT was downloaded

More info on command line parameters: [official docs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline).

Comment: i tried this but it is not working because the below mentioned code always returns 0 exit code, hence it is not going to errorlevel 1 :

> ftpcmd.dat (
    echo open sftp://<username>:<password><server_name> -hostkey="<server host key>"
    echo get /shared/sftp/test.csv
    echo exit
)
D:\Winscp\winscp.com /script=ftpcmd.dat